# Unit test in c# to check if "object.method" is called in Dictionary<int, object>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a class:

```
 public class ClassA
    {
       private Dictionary<int, object> myMap;
       ClassA
       {
        myMap.add(1,new object());
        myMap.add(2,new object())
        myMap.add(3,new object())
       }
    
    
       public void OnDataReceived(customData thecustomdata)
       {               
           myMap[1].Fire(thecustomdata.Name);
           myMap[2].Fire(thecustomdata.Name);
           myMap[3].Fire(thecustomdata.Name);
       }
    }
```

Unit test :

```
[TestMethod]
public void OnDataReceivedTester()
{
  //verify that the fire method of objects in the dictionary is called
  
}
```

I do not have an interface on ClassA so that i can put my dictionary in it and mock and verify which wld be easy(I know this way, but am not allowed to write an interface). Any other way so that i can verify if fire method on each object is called ?

Comment: Use a mocking library?

Comment: `Dictionary` has no `add` method. `object` has no `Fire` method. Please post relevant code.

Comment: You can mock nonvirtual method with the help of unconstrained frameworks such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect.

Answer (score -1):

My first inclination would be to re-write OnDataReceived to loop over `myMap.Values` and call `Fire` on each of them, at which point I wouldn't feel a need to unit test that particular method.

But if your team is convinced everything needs to be unit tested, then they should certainly allow you to redesign the class to use dependency injection. The dictionary could be either injected directly or retrieved from a separate service class that gets injected. Then you can mock/fake the injected object in your unit tests.

```
void Main()
{
    var thingMock = new Mock<Thing>();
    var customData = new object();
    var subject = new ClassA(new Dictionary<int, Thing>() { [1] = thingMock.Object });
    subject.OnDataReceived(customData);
    thingMock.Verify(t => t.Fire(customData), Times.Once());
}

public abstract class Thing { public abstract void Fire(object data); }
public class ClassA
{
    private IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Thing> myMap;
    public ClassA(IReadOnlyDictionary<int, Thing> map)
    {
        this.myMap = map;
    }


    public void OnDataReceived(object thecustomdata)
    {
        foreach (var value in myMap.Values)
        {
            value.Fire(thecustomdata);
        }
    }
}
```